# Cannot update a dependency in IntelliJ

Tags: java, maven

I'm trying to add a dependency into a Maven project in IntelliJ, which seemed to "work" for the pom.xml file as the dependency is not greyed out in IntelliJ.  However, there seems to be no way to reference this in my actual project.  Here is a screenshot to illustrate the issue:

[Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PwFqU.png)

As can be seen, the left hand and bottom areas show the dependency but not the right hand area, and no amount of reloading or invalidating caches seems to change this.

I imagine I'm missing something simple, but have of course no idea what.

*** What I did ***

Added the following to pom.xml:

```
      <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.javafaker/javafaker -->
      <dependency>
          <groupId>com.github.javafaker</groupId>
          <artifactId>javafaker</artifactId>
          <version>1.0.2</version>
      </dependency>
```

Attempted to include dependency with in a .java file with the following:

[import attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aYzGV.png)

Also here's some extra information (this time with a slightly different dependency), if useful:

[Another screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/19tyS.png)

Comment: What happens when you click the "Reload All Maven Projects" icon (two circular arrows - first icon in the tool bar) in the maven tab?

Comment: Usually that helps, but not in this case for some reason.  Or, at least, I see no obvious change.